# AutoLayout Dynamic Width UILabel

Tags: xcode, autolayout, uilabel

I'm trying to make a `UILabel` with dynamic width with **AutoLayout**. Meaning on any screen size, is going to have a fixed height and a width that goes from 10 px from its superview left margin and 10 from the right. I also have another constraint 10 from the top. When I set those constraints and I update the frame however, this is what I get :

[image]

While this is how it's supposed to be :

[image: How the UILabel should look]

If you could please let me know what do you think could be the issue here that would be really appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what priority did you set for the traling?

Comment: I didn't change it, so 1000. Should I change it to something else? @Joshua

Comment: maybe you can set it to >=10@750 or something like that.

Comment: Would it always be 10 at that point though? And you mean @ priority = 750, right?

Comment: This is clearly not updated properly. Select the label and then update frame or may be your right constraint value is not 10. check that too.

Answer (score 1):

I tested the following constraints will create left margin of 10 from left and 10 from right.

[image: Constraints Preview]

When you had made these constraints goto Editor -> Resolve Auto Layout Issues -> All Views in View -> Update Frames

[image: Interface Builder Preview]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I originally made the view without constraints and now adding them. The one I'm working with is the first 'subView' to which I'm setting the constraints so if I update all the views a mess comes out. Also, at first I thought it was something with the superview constraints, but I checked and those constraints seem to work fine. Any other ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: Even if you don't update it will not effect your program, as it only updates the view in the editor. So test your program in simulator or ios device to see the results.

Comment: Oh no I did update them and all the views unfortunately go all over the places :/

Comment: As I said it will only effect the views in your editor. The views in simulator or iOS device will look same as after you update your views in editor. So updating the view has no effect when you test your software.

Comment: Oh, I apologize: I didn't catch that. I just tested it on my iPhone and unfortunately it's a bit of a mess on my iPhone as well.

Comment: Could it have something to deal with the fact that the superView, or the parentView is a `UIScrollView` ?

Comment: If there is a parent view then you need to set constraints for the child view related to that parent view.